# Best way to animate Constraint layout change on Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, user-interface, android-animation

I am creating an animation that would move, change content and size of Views in the Layout. I am using constraint layout. I have two xml files one for regular layout, one for layout that I need to transition to.

I need to change: Contraints, Text, Tex Size and Visibly of multiple views.

I tried using:

```
ConstraintLayout rootLayout = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.main);
ConstraintSet newConstraint = new ConstraintSet();
newConstraint.load(this, R.layout.activity_selected);

TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(rootLayout);
newConstraint.applyTo(rootLayout);
```

However this doesn't update the text size, as it is not part of the ConstraintLyout class

I also tried using

```
selectedScene = Scene.getSceneForLayout(sceneRoot, R.layout.activity_selected, this);
TransitionManager.go(selectedScene, set);
```

But this does not produce a nice animation and required additional complications such as creating up setEnterAction() etc

Is there an elegant way to animate Constraint Layout change while changing text and text size of the views

Answer (score -1):

When using constraint sets, you can only change the constraints of a view and not its properties like the text size, color etc. In order to animate those properties, I would prefer you to use the object animator instead. There you have lots of possibilities.